# MySQL error #1064 while creating stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Here is the code:

```
IF(selected_item_id IS NOT NULL AND selected_category IS NOT NULL) THEN

    IF(selected_item_id <> "all") THEN

        SELECT i.id, i.name, i.summary, i.description, i.location, c.name AS 'category_name' FROM items i, categories c WHERE i.category_id = c.id AND i.id LIKE selected_item_id;

    ELSE IF(selected_item_id = "all" AND selected_category <> "all" AND selected_category in (SELECT name FROM categories)) THEN

        SELECT i.id, i.name, i.summary, i.description, i.location, c.name AS 'category_name' FROM items i, categories c WHERE i.category_id = c.id AND c.name LIKE selected_category;

    ELSE IF(selected_item_id = "all" AND selected_category = "all") THEN

        SELECT i.id, i.name, i.summary, i.description, i.location, c.name AS 'category_name' FROM items i, categories c WHERE i.category_id = c.id;

    END IF

END IF
```

When I try to save it, I get :

MySQL Said: #1064 near 'END IF' at line 17 (that's the last END IF)

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to add space in between ELSE and IF. See [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html) for details. And end you END IF with semicolon.

Comment: OK. Now it works. I'll put this to be answer as soon as it allows it